# C++20 use concepts to enforce interfaces on classes

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm creating a wrapper for a json decoder.
Depending on the actual target different json parser 3rd parties are in use.
All of them share a common interface.

```
class IJsonDecoder
{
public:
/**
 * @brief Decodes the json object to a user speicifed type
 * @tparam T Type to decode to
 * @return decoded type
*/
template<typename T>
T decodeTo() const;


/**
 * @brief Returns the value of a specfied key
 * @tparam T Type of the value
 * @param strKey Name of the key. nested keys are possible for ex key.subkey.subsubkey
 * @return Value of the key
*/
template<typename T>
T getKeyValue(const std::string& strKey);
}
```

Now of course the usal way would be use virtual functions. However virtual functions have some unnecessary run time overhead (I know at compile time which 3rd Party to use).

I already use concepts to enforce some simple interfaces on classes. What I can't figure out is how to make concepts depend on a template parameter itself

```
///this is a simple interface
template <typename T>
concept ISomeSimpleIF= requires(T a)
{
  {a.data() } -> std::convertible_to<std::string>;  ///< Convertible to std::string
  {a.empty() } -> std::same_as<bool>;  ///< Check if data is empty
}
```

How can I make this depend on the return value T

```
///this defines the Interface for IJsonDecoder
template <typename JsonDecoderType_T, typename returnValue_T>
concept IJsonDecoder = requires(JsonDecoderType_T a, returnValue_T b)
{
  {a.decodeTo() } -> std::same_as<returnValue_T >;
  {a.getKeyValue() } -> std::same_as<returnValue_T >;
};
```

This throws a compiler error missing "<" when applying this concept

```
  template <IJsonDecoder S>
  void foo(S) {};
```

Is there a way to make concepts depend on other template parameters?
thx for your help

Comment: "have some unnecessary run time overhead" Have you measured it? How significant it is in your specific case? My uneducated guess is: not even a blip on the radar (but I'm known to be wrong at times, so profile and check).

Comment: For particular syntax issue look up the uses of keyword `requires`.

Comment: Hm wait a second, which virtual functions? All I see is function templates.

Comment: requiring `decodeTo` and `getKeyValue` to have the same return type is a bit sus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CRTP:

```
template <class Impl>
class IJsonDecoder
{
  public:
    template<typename T> T decodeTo() const
    {
      return (static_cast<const Impl*>(this))->template decodeTo<T>();
    }
    template<typename T> T getKeyValue(const std::string& strKey)
    {
      return (static_cast<Impl*>(this))->template getKeyValue<T>(strKey);        
    }
};

// elsewhere
template <class JsonDecoderImpl>
void someFunction(IJsonDecoder<JsonDecoderImpl>& jsonDecoder) 
{
   std::string s = jsonDecoder.template decodeTo<std::string>(); // e.g.
}
```

Implementations need to declare themselces like that:

```
class MyJsonDecoder : public IJsonDecoder<MyJsonDecoder>
{
  // ...
};
```

In your code that knows the implementation at compile time you can have:

```
MyJsonDecoder myDecoder;
someFunction(myDecoder);
```

and this will work, while

```
someFunction(notADecoder);
```

will induce a clear, short, user-friendly error message (as opposed to a hailstorm of template-induced error messages otherwise).

No concepts were harmed while producing this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The concept `IJsonDecoder` has two type parameters. When you use it as a template type constraint, the first is supplied for you, You still have to supply the second.

```
template <IJsonDecoder<SomeConcreteTypeThatFooExtracts> S>
void foo(S) {};
```

This does highlight that your concept `IJsonDecoder` doesn't match your original class `IJsonDecoder`. The class promises to be able to convert to **every** type, whereas the concept promises to convert to **one** type.

There is no concept that corresponds to your class, because that requires universal quantification.

Here is a concept that creates a family of constraints that your class satisfies.

```
template <typename JsonDecoderType_T, typename returnValue_T>
concept IJsonDecoder = requires(JsonDecoderType_T a, std::string b)
{
  { a.decodeTo<returnValue_T>() } -> std::same_as<returnValue_T >;
  { a.getKeyValue<returnValue_T>(b) } -> std::same_as<returnValue_T >;
};
```

Comment: There are many concepts, one for each type the class can decode to. The class simply satisfies all of them.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI yes, which means *a* concept can't be a replacement for that class

Comment: ? A concept is never a replacement for a class. A concept is a condition on a bunch of types. This concept is a contition on two types. If you mean that this concept cannot be used as a condition on a single type that behaves like `IJsonDecoder`, then formally you are right, it cannot. However one can do: this `class MyDummyClass{}; ... template <IJsonDecoder<MyDummyClass> S> ...` and *hope* that if a class satisfies 
`IJsonDecoder<MyDummyClass>`, then it will satisfy `IJsonDecoder<anything at all>`, which is strictly speaking not always true, but could be good enough.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI a class with only pure virtual member functions, aka an interface, can be replaced with a concept, if all the uses can statically know the the most derived type of the objects that will be passed

Comment: This class doesn't have virtual functions, it only has function templates. It is largely useless except as a documentation ("make your classes like this one"). The idea is to replace a piece of documentation with something enforceable at the language level. One can do that like I have shown (not perfect but that's the best C++ can have).

Comment: Or specify a default dummy type for `returnValue_T`, such as `template <typename JsonDecoderType_T, typename returnValue_T = int>`.

Comment: @Caleth i did test your concept propsoal, but it throws a compiler error (on latesest MSVC) (typename returnValue_T is not allowed) do you know how to fix it?